# NoBeanDefFoundException while initializing viewmodel using sharedViewModel

Tags: android-viewmodel, koin

I am trying to initialize my viewModel in Fragment by using `sharedViewModel()` method, but got `NoBeanDefFoundException`. Before I initialized it by using `activityViewModel()` method, but because of new argument in viewmodel constructor and due to the scope, I decided to use exactly `sharedViewModel()`, which cause the exception in my application. I have no idea, why my Koin can not create instance for my ViewModel, cause almost all code is the same as in previous application, where I used same methods and where all staff is working ok. I will leave here some code below and my exception.

How I started Koin framework

```
startKoin {
        androidContext(this@App)
        // declare modules
        modules(
            ...
            viewModels, // this is my koin module for viewmodels
            ...
        )
    }
```

My Koin module

```
val viewModels = module {
    viewModel { RegistrationViewModel(get()) } 
    ...
}
```

My ViewModule itself and the fragment that is use it

```
class RegistrationViewModel(
   private val receiveInviteUseCase: ReceiveInviteUseCase
): BaseViewModel() {

// fragment

class RegistrationFragment: AuthBaseFragment<RegistrationFragmentBinding>(RegistrationFragmentBinding::inflate) {

    private val vm: RegistrationViewModel by sharedViewModel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a definition for ReceiveInviteUseCase in your Koin module? If not, Koin has no way of knowing what the get() in your Koin viewmodel definition refers to. So either you have to make a definition for that object also, or you need to provide it as a parameter ([see Koin docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel#passing-parameters-to-constructor)). Here's an example of the latter:

Your viewmodel:

```
class MyViewModel(
    myStringParameter: String,
    myObjectParameter: MyObject,
) : ViewModel() {
    // Viewmodel stuff
}
```

Your Koin module:

```
val myModule = module { 
    myViewModel { params ->
        MyViewModel(
            myStringParameter = params.component1(),
            myObjectParameter = params.component2()
        )
    }
}
```

To inject into your fragment:

```
 private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel(
    parameters = { 
      parametersOf(myString, myObject)
    }
)
```

The cases where I've used this has been where data produced in fragmentA is required to instantiate the viewmodel in fragmentB. The required data is passed as arguments to fragmentB and from there used for the viewmodel.

Btw: if you only need the viewmodel in that one fragment and not multiple, you can use regular ViewModel, as SharedViewModel is for sharing between activity and fragment(s), and probably has a different lifecycle.